# Elixir Ecto Alter Query Based on Function Params

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a series of complex queries that I'm running in Elixir/Phoenix utilizing Ecto. These goal is to make these queries work for both creating new entries and updating previous rows. To do this I envision using a function parameter that would define whether or not we are updating the tables. For example, right now I have the following function:

```
# Retrieves the stats on the user chargebacks
defp get_chargebacks(%{user_id: user_id} = map) do
    query =
      from u in Users,
      left_join: c in ChargeBacks, on: [user_id: u.id],
      where: u.id == ^user_id,
      select: %{chargeback_amount_cents: sum(c.amount), chargeback_amount_count: count(c.user_id), chargeback_amount_currency: @default_currency},
      group_by: u.id
    result = query
    |> RepoBVCore.one
    Map.merge(map, Map.put(result, :chargeback_amount_cents, Map.get(result, :chargeback_amount_cents) || 0))
end
```

I would like to change the function so that it would be the following:

```
defp get_chargebacks(%{user_id: user_id} = map, is_update \\ false)
```

And if `is_update = true` then I would want to add an additional `where` clause to the function (e.g.):

```
where: c.amount > 100
```

How can I alter my original function to conditionally alter the query statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access `c` by passing a list of 2 names as binding to `Ecto.Query.where/3`. `c` will be the second item in that list since it's the first `join` in the original query (the source table is the first one, the joins are after that in the order that they were joined in the original query):

```
defp get_chargebacks(%{user_id: user_id} = map, is_update \\ false) do
  query =
    from u in Users,
    left_join: c in ChargeBacks, on: [user_id: u.id],
    where: u.id == ^user_id,
    select: %{chargeback_amount_cents: sum(c.amount), chargeback_amount_count: count(c.user_id), chargeback_amount_currency: @default_currency},
    group_by: u.id
  query =
    if is_update do
      query |> where([u, c], c.amount > 100)
    else
      query
    end
...
```